# Android Studio - Fraction values must be in the range 0 to 1: 3.0

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:width="1080dp"
android:height="592dp"
android:viewportWidth="1080"
android:viewportHeight="592"
tools:ignore="VectorRaster">
<path
    android:pathData="M0,440.31L0,0L1080,0L1080,440.31C952.58,532.86 758.02,592 540,592S127.42,532.86 0,440.31Z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient
            android:startY="14.208"
            android:startX="-280.8"
            android:endY="380.656"
            android:endX="921.24"
            android:type="linear">
            <item android:offset="0" android:color="#602EC4"/>
            <item android:offset="1" android:color="#9C7CDD"/>
            <item android:offset="3" android:color="#8355D1"/>
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
```

> I am using this code to create a drawable for my app. but I keep getting this error: Fraction values must be in the range 0 to 1: 3.0. My Android Studio Version is 3.6.2